# Using exported (From Workspace Block) Signal in Simulink as input signal to a filter

Tags: matlab, array-signal-processing, simulink

I have generated some ECG Signals in MATLAB workspace and then exported the signal data in the Simulink using the from Workspace Block. Now, I want to use the exported signal as an input signal to a filter network. How can I use this exported data as input signal. I am attaching the Simulink model diagram for better understanding. Simulink Block Diagram of the System

I have tried connecting the output of the From Workspace block to input it in the filter network. I have also tried it using From File block to d[image]o the same. But I end up at the same point at not connecting the output to any of the point in my filter network.